# How to install Crusader Kings 2?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install a 'launcher' for the game Crusader Kings 2, so that I can get the DLC I bought for it to work. Why is it that whenever I try and lookup directions on how to do something with the terminal, it is always incomprehensible gibberish to me? I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for over a year now, and I've tried to avoid ever having to do anything with terminal, because I might as well be dealing with Egyptian heiroglyphs.

http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:sxxxx&package=qtck2launcher

How do I install this. Please be very clear, the terminology typically thrown around on help pages usually stumps me.

I tried just copying and pasting the code on that page, but it says 
permission denied. How exactly do I 'run' said code as 'root'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run these four commands in the terminal (one after another!):

```
wget -qO - http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:sxxxx/xUbuntu_12.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add - 
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:sxxxx/xUbuntu_12.04/ /' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtck2launcher.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtck2launcher
```

Comment: To the moderator: OK, sorry about the counter-editing, thanks for the help. I just saw the user was following the commands from a website and added the sudo su at the beggining becaus obviously he was doing it without root privileges. Thanks!

Comment: The website implies the user should use `sudo su`, which would be fine on distributions with a much simpler `sudo` policy, but it is not the case with Ubuntu. It is better to use `sudo <command>` for reasons such as that the environment variables are kept this way. Your answer is still 100% valid and I didn't mean to be intrusive. Both ways, with or without `tee`, do the exact same thing: not using `sudo su` is more of a healthy habit forming thing.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just had problems in the past with sudo combined with echo, so I assumed becoming root for the three commands would be easier. It's my fault anyway, because to be honest, I didn't know about the  "tee" command, I'll do a man research on it, I apologise, many thanks!

Comment: That's why we have editable answers!